# Functional Equation $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$.

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

If $f: \mathbb N \mapsto \mathbb N$ is one-to-one and $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$, what is the smallest possible value of $f(999)$?

Easily $f(1)=1$, and I think $f(n)=n$ must be the only map, but not able to prove it. The other alternative is if $f(999) = f(3)^3f(37) \ge 24$, which looks somehow odd.

Comment: Just to clarify, the functional equation holds for any pair of integers $m$ and $n$?

Comment: @SammyBlack It holds for any pair of natural numbers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do believe your answer $24$ is correct. The functionnal $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$ has the awesome characteristic to be totally powerless towards prime numbers. Really, if $p$ is prime, you can assign $f(p)$ whichever prime value you want, and you are sure to not make collisions if you select a different prime for all the prime numbers.

It is even more powerful than that : since the prime number decomposition always exists and is unique, giving a value to all the prime numbers defines $f$.

As you said, $f(999) = f(3)^3f(37)$ so the weight of $f(3)$ is higher than the weight of $f(37)$. It is then minimal to say that $f(3) = 2$ and $f(37) = 3$, $2$ and $3$ being the smallest numbers above $1$ (and happen to be prime, which simplifies the mapping). Then $f(999) = 24$.

EDIT : @Henry suggested to complete the map with $f(2) = 37 ; f(3) = 2 ; f(37) = 3 ; f(p) = p$ if $p$ is prime and different of $2,3,37$ which is totally correct.
Of course, $f(1) = 1$ and $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: +1: You could complete an example definition with $f(2)=37$ and $f(p)=p$ for primes other than $2,3,37$.

Comment: Looked weird, but can't find any problem with the e.g. @Henry suggests. Thanks.

Comment: $f(p)$ is not necessarily prime for all primes $p$.  For example, you could have $f(2) = 12$, $f(3) = 18$ and $f(p) = p^p$ for all other primes.